# MATLAB: How to publish figures in line instead of the bottom

Tags: matlab, position, publish, figure

Matlabs 'publish' function creates a html with all my code, comments and figures. However, I would like the figures to appear at the location where I give the plot command (like e.g. in iPython) and not at the bottom like Matlab (R 2010b) does. I have looked at the 'Edit publish configurations' of publish but could not find the appropriate setting.

Here is an example, where I would expect the figures to be plotted before the next data set is defined, however Matlab (R 2010b) plots them all the bottom.

```
data1 = 1:10

figure
plot(data1)

data2 = 5:15

figure
plot(data2)

data3 = 1:30

figure
plot(data3)

data4 = 5:50

figure
plot(data4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put each plotting command within its own cell (defined by a `%%` line), for example:

```
%%
data1 = 1:10

figure
plot(data1)

%%
data2 = 5:15

figure
plot(data2)

%%
data3 = 1:30

figure
plot(data3)

%%
data4 = 5:50

figure
plot(data4)
```

When publishing a script, cells get processed one by one, and the output gets held together in one place. You can include headings for each cell following the `%%` characters.

Comment: To extend this answer, the publishing tool's behavior is demonstrated in [this documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html)